# Different linker options for each executable

Tags: cmake, linker

I would like to create two separate executable from the same source files but with different linker parameters.

With the lines above, I can generate one executable without problem:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} --specs=nano.specs -T libs.ld -T mem.ld -T sections.ld -L\"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script\" -Wl,-Map,${MAP_NAME}")

add_executable(${ELF_NAME} ${PRJ1_SOURCE_FILES} ${PRJ1_HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${ELF_NAME} PRIVATE liba libb libc)
```

When I add the following two lines at the end of the code above, I can very well generate the second executable (with the same linker flags) besides the first one without problem:

```
add_executable(${ELF2_NAME} ${PRJ1_SOURCE_FILES} ${PRJ1_HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${ELF2_NAME} PRIVATE liba libb libc)
```

But my problem is that I have to generate the second executable (at the same time with the first one) with different linker parameters. I don't want to use conditional statements to generate one after another. My goal is to automate the process.

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set_target_properties` with `LINK_FLAGS` property. From [`set_target_properties manual`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/set_target_properties.html):

> set_target_properties(target1 target2 ...
>                         PROPERTIES prop1 value1
>                         prop2 value2 ...)
>   Set properties on a target.
>   ...
>   See Properties on Targets for the list of properties known to CMake.

In the link properties on targets we can find [LINK_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/prop_tgt/LINK_FLAGS.html):

> Additional flags to use when linking this target.
>
> The LINK_FLAGS property can be used to add extra flags to the link step of a target. LINK_FLAGS_ will add to the configuration , for example, DEBUG, RELEASE, MINSIZEREL, RELWITHDEBINFO.

So use something similar to:

`set_target_properties(${ELF_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS " --specs=rdimon.specs")`

Answer (score 0):

While Kamil answer is good for now, I believe question you're asking for is properly addressed in upcoming CMake v3.13.

**target_link_options** was introduced for that purpose,

"Specify link options to use when linking a given target. The named  must have been created by a command such as add_executable() or add_library() and must not be an ALIAS target."

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/target_link_options.html#command:target_link_options